# If Try statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, error-handling

In my scripts I wanna cleanup my error Handling. What I read is that I need:

```
try:
    do something
exept:
   raise Error("give error")
finaly:
    print("something else")
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to handle an error in this way in my former written function.
How do I create a try statement with multiple conditions like the simple example below.

```
def varlist(var, length):
    from numpy import array
    if len(array(var)) > length:
        return(False)
        raise ValueError('list is to long only first ' + str(length) + ' paramerets will be used')
    elif len(array(var)) < length:
        return(False)
        raise ValueError('list is to short ' + str(length) + ' is less than required')
    else:
        return(True)
```

So in general my question is: How to handle an if/ try statement with multiple outputs all baased on their value....
In this case I have two outputs but I have others with more values( sometimes strings)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your problem but here is a code using the try statement:

```
      def varlist(var, length):
         from numpy import array
         try:
             return True
         except len(array(var)) > length :
             return False
             raise ValueError('#Your Error message 1')
         except len(array(var)) < length :
             return False
             raise ValueError('#Your Error message 2')
```

If you meant how to return multiple values, just 'pack' them in a tuple like this:

```
    returntuple = ('statement1', 'statement2', etc)
    return returntuple
```

Then you can 'unpack' it like this:

returntuple[1]

will return `'statement2'`

Like this you can return multiple values. You need to trick python, because it doesn't provide returning multiple values(, as far as I know!). But if you 'pack' your values in a tuple or a listeverything is fine!

If those two answers doesn't get your problem, I'm sorry I just don't get the question.

Sincerely, heureka

Comment: Your answer don work... when i have the following input: `import numpy as np`   ;
`a = np.arange(3)`   ;
`b = 2`   ;
`c = varlist(a,b)`   . Then returns C as a `True` while this has to be a `False`

Comment: The long version it is more like: `If sin` ; `elif cos` ; `elif tan' ; `elif etc`
So the series are base on correct values